# R coerce multiple columns in frame

Tags: r, coercion

I have a data frame, call it f, and I want to coerce the first three columns from factors to character strings.

**f[,1] = as.character(f[,1])**

seems to work (and with columns 2 and 3).
But when I try to do this:

**f[,1:3] = as.character(f[,1:3])**

all hell seems to break loose. It looks as though all the columns get joined together.
Can someone tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: If you need to change multiple column class use `lapply` i.e. `f[1:3] <- lapply(f[1:3], as.character)`

Comment: Thanks akrun. That is a help. But I must have some fundamental misconception about using vectors n these functions. I though that my code line which doesn't work would convert the first, then the second, and then the third columns. Is this unique os the as.* functions?

Comment: The data.frame is a list with columns as list elements having equal length.   For applying function in a list, we use the `lapply/sapply/mapply/rapply` family of functions.  Based on the `?as.character`,  ` for ‘as.character’ the default method
     calls ‘as.vector’, so dispatch is first on methods for
     ‘as.character’ and then for methods for ‘as.vector’`